# Jquery.mobile $.ajax complete gets called repeatedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

I'm using jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js and cordova-2.0.0.js (phonegap).

In my setup for my $.ajax call I set my params like this:

```
  success: onFetchOK,   // saves everything to the database
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      // show everything in the database
      showAllHeaders();
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("onFetchFailure: There was an error retrieving messages: \n"
            +"xhr: " + xhr.statusText 
            +"\nstatus: " +textStatus 
            +"\nerror: " +errorThrown.message);
      $('#fetch-result').html(textStatus);
  },
```

The function onFetchOK gets 18 message headers back from the server, each message header has a subject and a date/time and these get stored in the webdb using the phonegap webdb storage API.

If I drop and recreate the message table and run the app fresh, the complete: function gets called once for each of the 18 messages I receive so 342 message headers gets displayed (18x18+18).

No where in my code other than this one complete: does showAllHeaders(); get called.

I placed an alert inside showAllHeaders() and that alert gets triggered 18 times.

To narrow this down further I placed a loop counter inside my success: onFetchOK() like this:

```
var loopCount = 0;
// process each message
$.each(json.messages, function(index, msg)
{        
    // save each alert before displaying it
    webdb.addAlert(msg.msg_id, msg.title, msg.when);
    loopCount++;
});
alert("loopCount = " +loopCount);
```

When this alert is called it shows "loopCount = 18" and this is called only once.

If I exit the app, reload it and no new messages are pulled from the server then 18 message headers are displayed, which is exactly as it should be.

So, it appears that my complete: function() is being called repeatedly... once as it should and then 18 more times.

Anyone have any idea why this would be?

Comment: The information posted is not enough. Please post the whole AJAX script and the code which starts the AJAX call.

Comment: @ppetree, Did you try to debug it as I suggested? If yes, can you post some more info?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help without the actual code, but there are some thing you should try...

- Add an alert to the `complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {` function.
  this will help you to verify if the `complete` function has been called 18 times or just the `showAllHeaders()`
- Access the page via firefox, go to firebug screen, stand on the "net" tab and choose the XHR
  Under the XHR you can see all of the server responses, including data returned.
  Verified that the data returned is as expected
- Add the following line to your `showAllHeaders()` function

> try { throw new Error("dummy"); } catch (e) { alert(e.stack); }

This line will print a call stack and will tell you from where this function had been called